# Dwoo does not echo strings with utf8 characters

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8, character-encoding, zend-db, dwoo

I have got a strange problem with `Zend Framework` - I fetch data from MySql table that is set to `utf8_general_ci`.
I inserted some data with polish fonts like `ś ę ż...` and push that data to view (`Dwoo`).

```
    {foreach $units unit}
        <tr>
            <td>{$unit.id_unit}</td>
            <td>{$unit.name}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
```

If `$unit.name` contains polish characters - `Dwoo` does not echo anything - if not, it works.

I set in bootstrap

```
$db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
$db->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

but it did not help.
I have no more ideas.

**Edit:**
Problem is only on localhost machine (Windows) but with remote server (Linux) it is fine.

Comment: Are you sure Dwoo supports utf-8?

Comment: have you tried echoing out the data in the controller, before it gets to dwoo?

Comment: Yes - it echoes fine with all characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really strange, I did a minimal test case which works fine for me :

```
$dwoo = new Dwoo();
$tpl = new Dwoo_Template_String('{$var}');
$var = 'ś ę ż.';

echo $dwoo->get($tpl, array('var'=>$var));
```

Output is "ś ę ż." alright.

Comment: It is a mysql/php configuration fault only.

Comment: Well it's weird, if you can dump it correctly before it gets into dwoo. Maybe you did your data import incorrectly locally and your data inside sql isn't actually utf8 ?

Comment: btw I wonder why you didn't accept my solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005673/reassign-parent-variable-in-included-dwoo-template - it seemed less hackish than dropping stuff in the env var.

Comment: Nothing personall - I used my solution and it works for sure even it is a bit hackish. ;)